# crash application while delete section from UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In `tableview` I have many sections, on the top row of section I have a delete button, I want to do delete section after clicking button but its crashing please help me how can I do this?? here is the code...

```
//****** adding delete section button
     CellButton *_sectionButton = (CellButton*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
     _sectionButton.hidden = YES;
     _sectionButton.indexPath = indexPath;
     [_sectionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionDeleteButton:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)sectionDeleteButton: (id)sender
{
   CellButton *_secbtn = (CellButton*)sender;
   NSInteger sectionNumber = _secbtn.indexPath.section;
   [self.tableView beginUpdates];
   [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNumber] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

EDIT: The error messsage is:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1054 2013-07-04 04:25:15.921 estimation[9025:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted)

Comment: It would be recommended to add the error message to these kind of questions.

Comment: update your number of sections count in numberOfScetionsInTableview method after deleting the row.

Comment: @allprog this the error...     Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1054
2013-07-04 04:25:15.921 estimation[9025:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I described in the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns the previous number of sections. You must make sure that what you tell the table view to do also happens in the data source. That is, if you delete a section, then the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` must also return a number one less than before. The same stands for cells and everything else. This is probably described in the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage your number of sections in `numberOfSectionsInTableview:` delegate method

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  [MLControl shared].arrBuyList.count;//1;//[MLControl shared].arrBuyList.count;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
       // [tableView beginUpdates];
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row=%ld,indexPath.se=%ld",(long)indexPath.row,(long)indexPath.section);
        [[MLControl shared].arrBuyList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //    [tableView endUpdates];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem, but the reason is different from yours.

When I add a section for the tableView, I reload data with this method, this also crash logging like yours:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Why do I use this method to reload my table? If I only refresh cells, this works fine, but I forgot I want to change the sections. For more information: [**What is More reliable way to reload UITableView Data?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27873583/3395008)