# What is More reliable way to reload UITableView Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have found 2 functions to reload my rows of UITableView

1st.

```
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] 
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

2nd.

```
    [tableView reloadData];
```

What is more specific way to reload UITableView Data

Comment: The answer depends on what changes you made to the data source just beforehand. reloadData will always work but could be overkill. reload of just the visible rows might work or the app could crash.

Answer (score 1):

Both are "reliable" and possibly "specific" (depending on what you mean by specific) -- in fact, there are even more ways:

```
reloadData
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
reloadSections:withRowAnimation:
reloadSectionIndexTitles
```

Check the developer documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html) on the differences, but the short answer is that they are all reliable -- it just depends on how much information you want to reload, and if you want to do it with animation.

For example, if you only want to reload certain rows, you can use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.  If you want to reload a whole section, use `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`.

Comment: That means only difference is that the my first function reloads it with Animation and 2nd one not.

Comment: No, `reloadData` will reload all rows (only the visible ones will be _redisplayed_ at the time of the call).  `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` reloads only the visible ones -- the cells that are not visible will not be reloaded

Comment: No, That is inCorrect i tested it and reloadData only reloads visiblecells and its sections. While reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: only reloads the visible cells not even its sections.

Comment: From the documentation I linked to for `reloadData`: Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on.

Yes, that is correct for `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` assuming you're passing it `[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` -- remember, you can pass it other values.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may have two cases,

a) You've the table with at least a single section (with a title or returning a view for section)

- In this case, if you call `reloadData` then it'll also reload section too. But `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` will only reload the visible cells and not the section.

b) You've the table with at least a single section (without a title or returning a view for section)

- In this case, if you call `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` both will reload only the visible cells.

So which one is the better?

- As I explained, based on the case, you should call any of the one method. If you have sections which you don't want to reload then you should call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method. Or if you want to reload cells along with section then should call `reloadData` method.

Comment: I do know how it works but there was small confusion about more specific way to do it. You got my point thanks for your answer.