# Delete tableview cell crash swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

Hello i wanna delete tableview cell following error occur

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (5), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted)

Here is code

```
     override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

      return sectionTitle.count
    }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

          let sTitle = sectionTitle[section] as? String
          let sectionAnimals = dict.objectForKey(sTitle!) as! NSArray
          print(sectionAnimals)
          return sectionAnimals.count

     }

         override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                    let sTitle = sectionTitle.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as! NSString
        let sectionAnimals = dict.objectForKey(sTitle)
        let animal = sectionAnimals!.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSString
        cell.video_name.text = animal as String

        let sectionAnimals1 = dict1.objectForKey(sTitle)
        let animal1 = sectionAnimals1!.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSString
        cell.artist_name.text = animal1 as String
     }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        self.dict.removeObjectForKey(self.sectionTitle[indexPath.section])
        self.dict1.removeObjectForKey(self.sectionTitle[indexPath.section])
        self.dict2.removeObjectForKey(self.sectionTitle[indexPath.section])

        let newArr = NSMutableArray(array: self.sectionTitle)
        newArr.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.section)
        self.sectionTitle = newArr


        tableView.reloadData()
       tableView.endUpdates()

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468685/crash-application-while-delete-section-from-uitableview

Comment: Salam ..... Thanks for it!!!

Comment: W salam , No problem

Comment: Good its work thanks

Comment: first write answer below not in comment then i will accept your answer

Comment: hahah , yes , thanks next time